# How can I get compiled transclusion in an AngularJS directive/component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components, directive, transclusion

Let me start with what I want:

```
   <ellipsis>Text which can be truncated and displayed with an ellipsis</ellipsis>
or <ellipsis>{{ some.value.from.scope }}</ellipsis>
```

That's it. I just want to use transclusion in an AngularJS directive or component. But there's one hitch. I want it to produce this:

```
<div class="ellipsis" title="Transcluded contents">
  Transcluded contents
</div>
```

Now if it gets truncated and displayed with an ellipsis then you can hover over it and still see the full text. It's the insertion of that transcluded text into an attribute that blows everything up for me. At least, that is, if I want it to work with AngularJS in the transclusion as well.

I can do it with a super simple component like so:

```
angular.module('coreComponents')
    .component('ellipsis', {
        bindings: {
          content: '<'
        },
        template: '<div class="ellipsis" title="{{ $ctrl.content }}">{{ $ctrl.content }}</div>'
      });
```

But then I'm not using transclusion anymore. That would have to be used like this:

```
<ellipsis content="'Text which can be truncated and displayed with an ellipsis'"/>
<ellipsis content="some.value.from.scope"/>
```

Not exactly elegant.

So I stuck with trying to do something using the transclusion function AngularJS provides but whenever I got the data it was always just the raw text, not the final value based upon what was in the surrounding scope. So, please show me how I could build a simple directive or component which would do this. Because I've tried and tried and tried without success to pull that off. What am I missing?

Don't ask me for what I've tried, the answer is every variant of $transclude().text() and $transclude($scope, (content) => { something }); I was able to imagine. I don't even have a record of them because I literally spent three hours trying different versions and none of them gave me a compiled value back which I could put into the component's scope or use $element.attr() to set the title on the element with whatever was passed in. I've read every question on here about transclusion and I didn't see any which made this work (though I did find several examples where if I substituted a value like '{{ something.in.scope }}' into them, they failed).

Comment: There is no problem just use transclude, but you can not use transclude in title... Best I can see is to bind to hover event and update title there, which is already something weird. Not saying that determining whether content was truncated using ellipsis is another thing which will require some ugly code. So I really suggest you to stick your "Not exactly elegant" solution.

Comment: Have you already checked how ng-transclude works? It is [deadly simple](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.12/src/ng/directive/ngTransclude.js#L68-L71), you can clone it and modify to your requirements (btw, how this should be handled if there are multiple tags in directive?). If directive content is supposed to be simple (a static string or an expression), an expression with a filter is much more straightforward approach (getting text from DOM is slow).

Comment: @estus Yes, it's true, ng-transclude is super simple, but it's relying on other code to take the "clone" variable you see in the code you referenced (which is not simple text, it's a set of DOM-like nodes and accompanying data) and put that into the element. In this case I need just the final compiled form of that data, not for insertion into the DOM but in the text form you or I would see if we looked at the HTML. Because that's what would go into the title attribute.